# On singular points of parallels

Tags: differential-geometry

Say $\gamma$ is a unit speed curve and its parallel is given by

$$ p (t) = \gamma (t) + d n(t)$$

where $n$ is the unit normal vector and $d$ is some scalar.

I read that

> The parallels of a smooth regular curve have an ordinary cusp
>   singularity at regular points of the evolute

But I think there is something wrong with this statement:

Consider an ellipse $\gamma (t) = (a \cos t , b \sin t)$. Drawing a picture:

[image]

where the ellipse is drawn in black, evolute in red and parallel in green, we see that there are supposed to be 4 ordinary cusp singularities (where the evolute intersects the parallel).

But clearly, the green curve does not have a cusp where it intersects the red curve.

> Please could someone tell me what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

This is because you have only a parallel outside of the original curve. Start drawing in the inside (or, in general, on the side to which the curve, uhm, curves).

**Edit (to answer a question in a comment):** Note that not every point on the evolute is regular, but the regular points are those where you can say something, cause there you can do differential calculus. In your example the statement you are worrying about does not make any claims about the nonregular points of the evolute (the cusps in your red curve). The point is that you need to look at the paralleles in direction of the inner normal to the ellipse. These may well be curves outside the ellipse, if the parallels are taken at a distance bigger then the diameter of the ellipse. What you need to look at is not the intersection of the green curve with the red curve, but the intersection of the set at distance $d$ in direction of the interior normal with the red curve. At the point where your green curve intersects the red curve is another point of another parallel to the ellipse, and that one is a cusp of that distance set.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'm still confused! Should "The parallels of a smooth regular curve have an ordinary cusp singularity at regular points of the evolute" really be "**Some** parallels of a smooth regular curve have an ordinary cusp singularity at regular points of the evolute"? It's a theorem and it sounds to me as if even the outside parallels should have cusps where they intersect the evolute.

Comment: Maybe I misread the sentence: is not every point on the evolute singular?

Comment: @astudent I added an explanation to my answer which, hopefully, answers your question.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'm still confused though: taking the derivative of the parallel shows that a point on the parallel is singular if and only if it is on the evolute. Therefore any point of intersection of the green curve with the red curve should be a singular point of the green curve, no?

Comment: I think I got it: the points of intersection of the green curve and the red curve are of the form $p(t_0) = e(t_1)$ in general (e.g. in the picture above). But we only get cusp singularities if the points are of the form $p(t_0) = e(t_0)$. Is that right?

Comment: The points on the green curve are all regular. The green curve is parallel to the ellipse wrt to the outward unit normal. Since the ellipse is strictly positively curved there are no singular points. Only on parallels wrt to the interior normal you will get singular points. Start drawing parallel curves to the ellipse in the interior. The first two singularities will occur at the left and right cusp of the red curve -- these are not covered by your theorem as the evolute is not regular there. Then increase the distance a little more, and you'll get singularities along the red curve.

Answer (score 1):

The tangent vector $p'(t)=\gamma'(t)+dn'(t)=(1-kd)\gamma'(t)$ vanishes when $k=1/d$, when it is a singular point of $p(t)$. It is on the evolute. As Thomas pointed out they are at the inner side.

Comment: Maybe I misread the sentence: is not every point on the evolute singular?

Comment: when a point of p(t) is also on the evolute, it implies kd=1 thus $p'(t)=0$, it must be singular.